# Match 10 digit alternating numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex which matches 10 digit alternating numbers like `1212121212` `3434343434` so on. I know this is not right way to ask here. But I tried a lot from my side I was not able to figure out so reaching out for help.

It cannot be 1313131313. I should be the next number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is always 10 characters long and we always have single-digit numbers then simply take the first two characters, repeat 5 times and compare:

```js
const check = str => {
  const a = +str[0];
  const b = +str[1];
  return a+1 === b && `${a}${b}`.repeat(5) === str;
};

check('1212121212');
//=> true

check('1212121215');
//=> false

check('1313131313');
//=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and specify a length and an offset to get the alternation for the next number:

```js
const alternating = (len, offset) =>
  Array.from({ length: len }, (_, index) => (index % 2) + offset).join('');

console.log(alternating(10, 1) === "1212121212");
console.log(alternating(10, 3) === "3434343434");
console.log(alternating(10, 2) === "1313131313");
```

Answer (score 1):

For pure regex you would just have to work out the different combinations because regex doesn't support the concept of numbers nor their sequence; everything is a string of chars.

```
^(01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89)\1{4}$
```

If `9090909090` is valid then:

```
^(01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90)\1{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

If the repetition is always two figures you can do something like `(\d\d)\1{4}`.

This is create a group with two digits `(\d\d)`, find the same match as previous four times in a row `\1{4}`.

Comment: This would even match 3535353535. I want it in order like 3434343434. Is that possible

Comment: I think you should be better off building up the matches using the programming language you are using/used to. Something just like @customcommander posted.